# TreeViewItem event bubbles through parents

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I create a simple tree at runtime in my `TreeView`.

[image]

Each `TreeViewItem` has a mouse double click event that should print out the header of the item clicked and some information related to that item. However, if 6 was double clicked, the event would trigger on 6, and bubble up through each item. Even if the handled is set to true.

---

```
<Window x:Class="TreeBubbleIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="TestingTree" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TreeBubbleIssue
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RunTimeGeneratedTree();
        }

        private void RunTimeGeneratedTree()
        {
            TreeViewItem first = new TreeViewItem { Header = 1 };

            string randomString = RandomString();

            first.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{first.Header}: {randomString}");
                args.Handled = true;
            };

            TreeViewItem last = first;

            for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem { Header = i };
                string otherInfoFromElseWhere = RandomString();
                item.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Header}: {otherInfoFromElseWhere}");
                    args.Handled = true;
                };

                last.Items.Add(item);
                last = item;
            }

            TestingTree.Items.Add(first);
        }

        private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

        public static string RandomString()
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 50)
                .Select(s => s[Random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A teeviewitem is a headereditemscontrol. 1 contains 2 which contains 3. Everything you're looking at is in treeviewitem 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5bcb70d2-ff6d-4289-8325-24212a08327e/cant-prevent-event-from-bubbling-up-in-the-treeview-control?forum=wpf) on the MSDN forums, this is the expected behavior. Although you handle the event, it will still bubble up. There are two workarounds that you can try.

- Check the `SelectedItem` in the event handler
- Check `OriginalSource` and find the first parent that is a `TreeViewItem`

As the first might not work for other click events, so I will show you an examle of the second.

```
item.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) =>
{
   if (FindParent<TreeViewItem>((DependencyObject)args.OriginalSource) == args.Source)
      Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Header}: {otherInfoFromElseWhere}");
};
```

```
public static DependencyObject FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
   while (dependencyObject != null && typeof(T) != dependencyObject.GetType())
      dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

   return dependencyObject;
}
```